# Custom Selector Names for Angular Material Components

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components

I am just getting started with angular and angular material and I am not enjoying how each angular-material component begins with `mat`.  For instance:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav>...</mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>...</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Is there a way for me to give custom selector names for these components?  I.e., something like this:

```
<SidenavContainer>
  <Sidenav>...</Sidenav>
  <SidenavContent>...</SidenavContent>      
</SidenavContainer>
```

If so, how could I do that?

Comment: Why you want that? There is no way to do that, unless you extend these components. Sounds ridiculous to do that just for this purpose. `selector` property is a part of components' metadata

Comment: I want to do it simply for personal preference.   However, I only want to do it if there is a simple and easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<SidenavContainer>` is a very React looking component.

Welcome to Angular...

The conventions are different and you'll get use to it over time, but the reason we have prefixes is because Angular and React resolve components very differently.

React can *import* a component reference, and you can rename the import if you have two components with the same name.

```
import {SidenavContainer} from './src/SidenavContainer';
import {SidenavContainer as SidenavContainerOther} from '../other/src/SidenavContainer';
```

Angular cannot *rename* a selector. They are in the *global* space of a project, and resolved at compile time by the AOT.

So we have to use a *prefix* to isolate our components from other people's components. So you would create `<app-sidenav-container>` and in that way it will not collide with `<mat-sidenav-container>` from another library.

Comment: Got it - thanks.  I must admit, I like the React style of components more, but I am learning Angular because I want the power and benefits of a full, integrated framework.